# Change color of specific keyword in RubyMine

Tags: themes, rubymine, color-scheme, jetbrains-ide

is there a way in RubyMine to change color of a specific keyword/string?

As an example, let's say in my code I use the word `abc` that is particularly important. Is there a way to change the color of this word (or its background) so that it's more highlighted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible unless you wrote a custom plugin for Rubymine. There is also an [open bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473) for this feature.